# Почему не срабатывает скрипт?

Tags: javascript, html

Я только начил изучать Js это еще первые шаги )немогу найти ошибку может от того что устал ..)Но  скрипт не работает

```
$('document').ready(function(){

    function system(){
   var a1 =$('#value1').val();
   if (a!=null){
       alert('nese var sende nese var nese');
   }else{
        alert('Plist insert value ');
   }
    }
  $('button').on('click',system());
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) `document` указывается без кавычек:

```
$(document).ready(function(){...});
```

2) `$(document).ready(function(){...});` - это не чистый JS, что бы оно запускалось, нужно подключить библиотеку Jquery

3) `function system(){...}` конечно можно указывать в *document ready*, но обычно её выносят за неё:

```
function system(){...};
$(document).ready(function() {...});
```

4) Запуск функции с кнопки можно сделать вот так:

```
$('button').on('click', system);
```

или так

```
$('button').on('click', function() { system() });
```

И это тоже не чистый JS, нужна библиотека Jquery

5) У вас переменные указаны по разному:

```
var a1 = $('#value1').val(); // Тут "a1"
if (a!=null){ // тут "a"
  ...
}else{
  ...
}
```

Измените на

```
var a1 = $('#value1').val();
if (a1 == null){
  ...
}else{
  ...
}
```

Comment: Да jquery я уже подключил

Comment: @elik, ну тогда одно из пунктов :)

Comment: хорошо спасибо !)

Comment: @elik, я ещё один пункт добавил

Comment: ааа вот в  чем едло переменные запутался ))понятно спасибо друг

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.button').on('click', function(){//Возможно, пропущен селектор класса '.', либо идентификатора '#'
    system(); //функции запускаются через анонимные
});
```

---

И да, там строчечка неприметная, но названия переменных разные:

```
var a1 =$('#value1').val();
if (a!=null){...}
```

**a1** и **a**

Сдается мне, что это и есть корень проблемы

Comment: `Пропущен селектор класса '.', либо идентификатора '#'` - скажу по секрету, есть такой тег, как `<button>`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский кк поправил, спасибо